# VScode node debugger throws Uncaught Error: write EPIPE

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to run the debugger, I keep getting this error:

[image: VScode debugger console error]

This is the debug configurations:

```json
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
  {
   "type": "node",
   "request": "launch",
   "name": "Launch Program",
   "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/bin/www",
   "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/server/.env"
  }
 ]
}
```

**---- Update ----**

I am using VScode version 1.49.0

Comment: VScode recommenced a fix add "outputCapture": "std". See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/106484#issuecomment-691202789

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [@S.Clarke876](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9890007/s-clarke876) mentioned, it appears to be a bug in VS Code, that should be fixed in the next release. See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/106484#issuecomment-691202789

You can work around the issue by adding `"outputCapture": "std"` to your `launch.json` file.

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
  {
   "type": "node",
   "request": "launch",
   "name": "Launch Program",
   "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/bin/www",
   "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/server/.env",
   "outputCapture": "std"
  }
 ]
}
```

Worked for me! It only appeared to happen when the npm package `debug` attempted to write out to the console. I.e. `console.log` was fine.

Thanks again, [@S.Clarke876](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9890007/s-clarke876)! Only adding this answer as I nearly missed your comment.